# Pandas groupby and sum with the current month

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

This is the first 10 lines of the df that I am working with:

```
     id        user_id  session_date mb_used

0   1000_13     1000    2018-12-29  89.86
1   1000_204    1000    2018-12-31  0.00
2   1000_379    1000    2018-12-28  660.40
3   1000_413    1000    2018-12-26  270.99
4   1000_442    1000    2018-12-27  880.22
5   1001_0      1001    2018-08-24  284.68
6   1001_3      1001    2018-12-09  656.04
7   1001_4      1001    2018-11-04  16.97
8   1001_10     1001    2018-11-27  135.18
9   1001_15     1001    2018-12-13  761.92
```

My question is: how do I find the total amount of mb_used for each user_id per month? This means I would have to first isolate each user_id, find out how many rows did they use data in the same month, and then add those to get the 'data used per month' for each user. I can use pivot tables to find the total data used by each user using this code:
`internet_per_user = pd.pivot_table(internet, index = 'user_id', columns='mb_used',aggfunc='sum')`
But I am not able to incorporate the per month aspect.

For the 10 rows posted above, I would expect the output to look like this (hand-calculated):

```
user_id Month mb_used
1000    12    1901.47
1001    08    284.68
1001    12    1417.96
1001    11    152.15
```

Comment: What does the output look like, does `df.groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='session_date', freq='M')])['mb_used'].sum()    ` work for you?

Comment: @cs95 what output are you referring to? I am not able to get the total mb_used for each user per month. I just ran your code and this is the error I got: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: You need to convert "session_date" to a datetime column first, use `df['session_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['session_date'], errors='coerce')` and then run the code in my comment above. "What output are you referring to", I'm referring to the output you're expecting to see for the problem and data described. It is always helpful to see the expected output (that means you have do some calculations by hand) so we can verify the code for correctness. Thank you.

Comment: @cs95, I understood, I edited the question accordingly. Thank you! I tried running the code you suggested, and it seems like it is working, but I am not sure what it is doing when the user has multiple months like the 1001 user in the example I showed

Comment: It groups your rows per user ID and every month for each user ID, and sums your data. Looks like your result is as expected. Is there a reason you believe the result is incorrect? It seems to correlate with your calculations as well. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How would I create the 'Month' column like I showed in my above calculation? I can try to verify with the help of that. Thank you.

Comment: I see. You can extract the month number from the date column, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to group on user ID for each month and perform a sum. You can use:

```
df['session_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['session_date'], errors='coerce')
(df.groupby(['user_id', df['session_date'].dt.month])['mb_used']
   .sum()
   .reset_index())

   user_id  session_date  mb_used
0     1000            12  1901.47
1     1001             8   284.68
2     1001            11   152.15
3     1001            12  1417.96
```